# Jaxb + xjc code generation with xsd:choice

Tags: jaxb, code-generation, xjc

We have been provided with a XSD document specifying the format for data transfer between two applications as XML documents. The mapping is not quite as I would like it to be, and I would like to customize it with a custom `.xjb` mapping file.

The xsd is as follows

```
<xsd:complexType name="selection">
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="area" type="area"/>
        <xsd:element name="range" type="range"/>
        <xsd:element name="exact" type="exact"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="area">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{2}"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="range">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="exact">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{5}"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

By default this generates the following `Selection` class

```
public class Selection {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "exact", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "range", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "area", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    protected List<JAXBElement<String>> areaOrRangeOrExact;
    ...
}
```

Preferably, I would like it to generate something like

```
public class Selection {
    protected List<Exact> exacts;
    protected List<Area> areas;
    protected List<Range> ranges;
    ...
}
```

Or, if they extended a superclass, say `SelectionType`

```
public class Selection {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "exact", type = Exact.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "range", type = Range.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "area", type = Area.class)
    })
    protected List<SelectionType> selection;
    ...
}
```

Can I achieve this without modifying the original XSD?